# What is the name of this partial differential equation?

Tags: reference-request

What is the name of the following equation?

$$f_t = \nabla \cdot(a(f)  \ \nabla f)$$

of course , if we removed the dependency of $a$ on $f$ then we would have the heat equation.

Comment: Does $f_t $ denote partial derivative of $f $ w.r.t. $t $?

Comment: yes!. Sorry I should have made that clear.